# How to recognize characters in image?

Tags: c#, ocr

I am developing a project in MVC C # where a photo of a tax coupon is taken on thermal paper and the system must interpret the characters of the photo to use later. I did tests with some OCR libraries (Tesseract-OCR for example, some paid as well), but so far none could recognize the characters with great need and reliably, I believe because of the image quality, print quality and font used. Does anyone have any better ideas than OCR or some way to improve their accuracy?

Many thanks for all the answers. The image in question would be this:
[tax coupon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doL37.jpg)

Comment: There is no idea other than OCR since that's exactly what OCR means: to interpret characters from an image. As far as I'm concerned, there is a limit to how good this can work. If the image quality is bad enough, then no one/thing can read it. Sounds like you might need to try more libraries or Google for OCR software reviewed. While someone might happen along that has a good suggestion, this might be outside the scope of a stackoverflow question.

Comment: If the photo of the tax coupon contains handwriting and not printed text than OCR will not produce accurate results.  You'll want to look at ICR technology(none free that I am aware of).  The quality of the image is also the biggest factor in obtaining accurate results. You're going to want an image with a resolution of 300 DPI or higher, anything lower and the results are poor.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'll provide the actual image sample.  Then I and others can visually evaluate it as well as try it in our various OCR software.

Comment: If one of the libraries you tried was LEADTOOLS and you did not get satisfactory results, you could contact us through our live chat or email support services (both are free) and we can check your images to see if they are likely to work with our OCR or ICR modules. If you haven't tried our SDK, there's a free evaluation edition on [our website](https://www.leadtools.com).

Comment: Many thanks for all the answers. 
Sorry, I could not put the image here so I put it inside the main question.